# Failed to Receive Data From a Form by Put Request - Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-8, put

I have a form to update the database but when I click submit, and the issue is the data is not passing to my resource controller ( The controller has received the request, but the $requst->input() and $request->all() are null ).

Am I doing anything wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

```
<form action="/Equipments/{{$equipment['Index']}}" method="post" id="equipment_edit_form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field("PUT") }}
  <div class="w-full rounded-lg shadow-lg p-4">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-2 col-span-8    col-start-3">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-2 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-first-name">
            Equipment Name
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-equipment-name" placeholder="{{$equipment['Equipment Name']}}" type="text"
              name="Equipment_Name">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-last-name">
            Equipment Category
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 mb-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment["Category"]}}"
              name="Equipment_Category">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-3 col-span-8 col-start-3">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-2 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-first-name">
            Serial Number
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
              id="grid-first-name" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment["Serial Number"]}}"
              name="Serial_Number">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-last-name">
            Manufacturer
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 mb-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Manufacturer']}}"
              placeholder="Yokogawa" name="Manufacturer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-4 col-span-8    col-start-3">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            Model
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
              id="grid-first-name" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Model']}}" name="Model">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-location">
            Location
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded mb-3 py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Location']}}"
              name="Location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-5 col-span-8    col-start-3">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            Calibration Date
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
              id="grid-first-name" placeholder="{{$equipment['Date of Calibration']}}" type="date"
              name="Calibration_Date">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-location">
            Next Due Date
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 mb-3 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-last-name" placeholder="{{$equipment['Next Due Date']}}" type="date"
              name="Next_Due_Date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-6 col-span-8    col-start-3">
      <div class="w-full px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            REGISTRATION TAG
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-password" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Registration Tag']}}"
              name="New_Registration_Tag">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-7 col-span-8    ">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            Upload Image
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-password" type="file" placeholder="5627" name="Equipment_Image">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            Upload Cal Cert
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-password" type="file" placeholder="5627" name="Equipment_Cert">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 row-start-7    col-span-8 col-start-3">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            Accredited
        </label>
        <div class="relative">
            <input
                class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                id="grid-password" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Accredited']}}"
                name="Accredited">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-location">
            Status
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-password" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Status']}}"
              name="Equipment_Status">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
            for="grid-model">
            Year of Purchase
        </label>
        <input
              class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-password" type="text" placeholder="{{$equipment['Year of Purchase']}}"
              name="Year_of_Purchase">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-4 mx-2 mb-6 col-start-3 col-span-8 row-start-4">
      <label class="block w-full">
          <span class="text-gray-700">Remark</span>
          <textarea name="Remark" class="form-textarea mt-1 block w-full" rows="3"
              placeholder="{{$equipment->Remark}}"></textarea>
      </label>
    </div>
    <button onclick="form_submit()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My Jquery code to submit the form

```
<script>
function form_submit() {
    document.getElementById("equipment_edit_form").submit();
   }    
</script>
```

Comment: Your JS `form_submit` function does nothing a normal form submission wouldn't do; it's totally redundant. Where does the `PUT` request from your title come into this?

Comment: initially I was using <button type="submit">Submit</button> but the form cannot be sent and I use JS as a workaround. I have specified the put request type in my HTML

Comment: What does that mean, _"the form cannot be sent"_?

Comment: the button does not trigger any submission

Comment: If you replace the button with `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` and it doesn't submit, then there is something stopping it that you have not shown in your code. The first thing I'd do is check the browser console for errors

Comment: Oh thank you. I got some hints and resolved the issue with my submit button but I still getting null from the request.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request. Make sure all the parameters are present and that it's posting to the correct route.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: When doing a PUT request, I'd go with Content-Type `application/json` so that I can access the payload via `$request->json('property')`